# Beta Status on posts per day

Tags: discussion, beta

Hi folks I have a simple question that some of you may already know the answer to.

The threshold for graduation is 10 questions/day and this seems to be all that's holding this site back from graduation.  Presently it's at 4.5/day according to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games).  However the thing that's also clear is that with almost 2000 days in beta our denominator is playing against the site.

For example: if the site had 1 full year of 10 posts per day, the average would be 5.37 posts/day ... 2 full years for 6 posts per day average .. 10 years of 10/day is 8.1/ppd, 25 years is 9.03/ppd, 175 years is 9.8 ... etc.

Yes, if the site moves over 10 per day the time drops accordingly (3 years of 20 ppd for the 10 average) but ... that's not the threshold, the threshold is 10.

Is it reasonable to look at a metric that captures a 6 month window of # of posts / days in 6 months?  As it stands now in order to move that number up will require years of 10+ posts per day, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: It's unclear at this point what, if anything, actually matters for graduation. Home Improvement, Christianity, Role Playing Games, and Photography graduated with around the same question rate we have now. Many other graduated sites have worse numbers in one or another of those statistics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hover over the "4.5 questions per day" box, the tooltip says

> 4.5 questions per day on average over the past two weeks.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes a great deal more sense.  When I was poking around I see the actual number of questions is around 6100 as opposed to my calculated number above -- I didn't know if that was due to deleted questions or what.  Your answer solves that mystery too.